# OpenGL ES 2.0 on Tegra2: How many GPU cores are used in glDrawArrays/glDrawElements functions?

Tags: opengl-es, multicore, gpu

Does Anybody have information about how much GPU cores will be used when I call `glDrawArrays`/`glDrawElements`?

A bit more details to explain my question.
Processor Tegra2 has 4cores GPU. To work libGLESv2.so is used.
After all preparatory works have been done (create and link shaders; upload textures and etc), I call DRAW function which started rasterization and create image in framebuffer. 
I think, DRAW function has to use as more cores as possible to do rasterizarion more fast.
But I can't found any documents which confirm my theory. 
Description of OpenGL has only information about there own level API, and, understandably, not any information about below levels. NVIDIA don't present description how libGLESv2.so is realized.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody don't want to answer, I will do it myself :)

After a few attempts, I got following results:
!!Please, note I use GPU to data computing. Using linear data arrays so screen is defined with height = 1 and wight = array size. In order to computing line with wight = array size is drawn.

1. DRAW functions use as much cores as possible.
2. But it depends on how much verteces are send to DRAW.
   For example: if line (2 vertices) is drawn one performance is got. If this line is divided on the several small lines (4 or more vertices), performance will be better.

All in all, as I suppose to use all cores is necessary to call DRAW with number of vertices at least equal the number of GPU cores . In my case computing was faster about 20% when line was divided on the two sublines. Following divide almost didn't give performance increasing.